# Colorpicker using jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to design a page which has a colorpicker to set the forecolor and backcolor of a text. I came through the demo of a colorpicker which seemed appealing and tried to implement the same on a pop-up. I would like to know whether there is anyone here who's familiar with the colorpicker described in the below link:

http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

The query is " is it possible to bind this plugin to a div with different name?" If yes, please feel free to help..

Comment: I don't understand the question. What to you mean with "bin to a div"?

Comment: I'm able to display the colorpicker by giving the 'id' as colorpickerholder, when i changes to a different text, it doesnt show. I need to display the same mode of colorpicker in two different divs.

Comment: Would be smarter from you and easier for us to show us the code you wrote so you can correct it for you...

Answer (score 3):

The page includes the following code snippet:

```
$('#colorpickerHolder').ColorPicker({flat: true});
```

The first part is a standard jQuery selector, so you should have noproblem replacing the ID for the div:

```
<div id="myPicker"></div>

// snip

$('#myPicker').ColorPIcker({flat: true});
```

On the invocation page of the website they have this, which suggests that maybe it works on an input field? I've downloaded the package and there's no better instructions. You might have to dig through the source code to see how it works.

> Invocation code All you have to do is to select the elements in a
>   jQuery way and call the plugin.  $('input').ColorPicker(options);

Comment: The author is using 3 types of colorpickers in the demo and the corresponding div is like colorpickerHolder,colorpickerHolder1,colorpickerHolder2. If i try to give anything else other than these, it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this color picker and it works fine. I think you are using the demo files for using this color picker. In the demo file "index.html", you can find code snippets like `$('#colorpickerHolder').ColorPicker({flat: true});` 
but making any changes here wont affect the working on page.

If you notice, the author has included a separate code file at the top

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/layout.js?ver=1.0.2">
    </script>
```

this file, layout.js contains all the calls to the function `ColorPicker`.

I would recommend you to create a fresh page, with just these lines at the top.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/colorpicker.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#colorpickerHolder').ColorPicker({
                flat: true
            });
            $('#myColorpickerHolder').ColorPicker({
                flat: true
            });        
         });
    </script>
```

Now, just add two divs with IDs "colorpickerHolder" and "myColorpickerHolder" in the page, you will see each one is a separate color picker.

Comment: Hi Danish, first of all thanks for the response. I would like to know whether the same can be done with the second colorpicker shown in the demo,i.e. the one used with 'colorpickerHolder2' . I'm not able to bind the preview color to an input field using the above one. Do you know how to bind the submitted color to an input field using the one in you code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#FieldID').ColorPicker({
    onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
            $(el).val(hex);
    $(el).ColorPickerHide();
    },
    onBeforeShow: function () {
        $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
    }
    }).bind('keyup', function(){
        $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
    })
});
```

You can replace the `#FieldID` with a coma separated list of field IDs (prepended with #(sharp)) and/or classes (prepended with .(dot)) and/or any CSS selector.